# Best way to get JSON from struct vector class

Tags: json

I have a vector which consist of a struct, see below:

```cpp
struct FileInformation
  {
    String name;
    size_t filesize;
  };
    
std::vector<FileInformation> FileInformations;
```

How do I get JSON out of it the easiest way?

Comment: `for` cycle and `print`?

Answer (score 1):

Using [ArduinoJson](https://arduinojson.org):

```cpp
DynamicJsonDocument doc(2048);
for (const FileInformation& item : FileInformations) {
  JsonObject& obj = doc.createNestedObject();
  obj["name"] = item.name;
  obj["filesize"] = item.filesize;
}
serializeJson(doc, Serial);
```

This will produce a JSON document that looks like this:

```cpp
[
  {"name": "command.com", "filesize": 1234},
  {"name": "config.sys", "filesize": 2345},
  {"name": "autoexec.bat", "filesize": 3456}
]
```

Please read [the tutorial](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/serialization/) for more information.